# Adding latest quantity value as part of event source event

Tags: event-sourcing

According to my understanding I have to "construct" the latest state of the system by iterating over all events for the given aggregator. If I need to find the latest quantity for a product I have to iterate over each events that added or deducted quantity from the particular item. Can I however append the "latest" quantity of that product as part of the given event? So instead of having events like {added: 3}, {deducted: 1} = 2 available, I can have {added: 3, available: 3}, {deducted: 1, available: 2} so that I can just grab the last event from the store instead of iterating over all of them OR keeping a snapshot. Is this against the "rules" and what are the possible implications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general rule is that an event should not contain computed values, but at the same time its a trad-off between complexity and ease of use.

An alternative is to rely on snapshots, IF the performance is an issue. However, in my cases the read-side can handle those aggregated questions for you. You should also not be afraid of having to load a set of events to get to the current state of a given aggregate.